# Index of a random number in a list?

Tags: python, random, position, indexof

So I've looked for help elsewhere but couldn't find any solution. I've created a list with 51 elements and would like to pick 10 random, different positions within that list and be able to change the value at those positions(you can see this under the `assignCard(person)` function). Since I am using the index of the numbers I can't use methods such as `random.sample` or put the random numbers into a `set()` because I get an error message. Ive posted my code below, feel free to copy and run it to view the output, everything works except for the repeating numbers so if possible please do not change the code drastically in your answer.

```
""" cardGame.py
    basic card game framework
    keeps track of card locations for as many hands as needed
"""
from random import *
import random

NUMCARDS = 52
DECK = 0
PLAYER = 1
COMP = 2

cardLoc = [0] * NUMCARDS
suitName = ("hearts", "diamonds", "spades", "clubs")
rankName = ("Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", 
            "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King")
playerName = ("deck", "player", "computer")

def main():
  clearDeck()

  for i in range(5):
    assignCard(PLAYER)
    assignCard(COMP)

  print(cardLoc)

  print("#  " + " card      " + " location")
  showDeck()
  print("\nDisplaying player hand:")
  showHand(PLAYER)
  print("\nDisplaying computer hand:")
  showHand(COMP)

def clearDeck():
    cardLoc = [0] * NUMCARDS

def assignCard(person):
  x = random.randint(0, 51)
  cardLoc[x] = person

def showDeck():
  for i in range(NUMCARDS):
    y = rankName[i % 13]
    z = suitName[int(i / 13)]
    a = cardLoc[i]
    b = playerName[a]
    print("{:<4}{:<4} of {:<14}{:<7}".format(str(i), y, z, b))

def showHand(person):
  for i in range(NUMCARDS):
    if cardLoc[i] == person:
      print(rankName[i % 13] + suitName[int(i / 13)])

main()
```

Answer (score 3):

> Since I am using the index of the numbers I can't use methods such as `random.sample`

Sure you can:

```
>>> import random
>>> my_list = [0]*10
>>> my_list
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> idx = list(range(len(my_list)))
>>> idx
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> s = random.sample(idx, 5)
>>> s
[4, 0, 5, 7, 1]
>>> for i in s:
...     my_list[i] = 99
...
>>> my_list
[99, 99, 0, 0, 99, 99, 0, 99, 0, 0]
```

Here, just do something like:

```
>>> NUMCARDS = 52
>>> cardLoc = [0]*52
>>> s = random.sample(range(NUMCARDS), 10)
>>> for i in s[:5]:
...     cardLoc[i] = 1
...
>>> for i in s[5:]:
...     cardLoc[i] = 2
...
```

Now I'm just printing the positions:

```
>>> for i in range(NUMCARDS):
...     if cardLoc[i] == 1:
...         print(i)
...
10
24
25
34
41
>>> for i in range(NUMCARDS):
...     if cardLoc[i] == 2:
...         print(i)
...
14
23
28
49
50
>>>
```

Or, loading up your constants:

```
>>> NUMCARDS = 52
>>> DECK = 0
>>> PLAYER = 1
>>> COMP = 2
>>>
>>> cardLoc = [0] * NUMCARDS
>>> suitName = ("hearts", "diamonds", "spades", "clubs")
>>> rankName = ("Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven",
...             "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King")
>>> playerName = ("deck", "player", "computer")
>>>
>>> s = random.sample(range(NUMCARDS), 10)
>>> for i in s[:5]:
...     cardLoc[i] = PLAYER
...
>>> for i in s[5:]:
...     cardLoc[i] = COMP
...
>>> def showHand(person):
...   for i in range(NUMCARDS):
...     if cardLoc[i] == person:
...       print(rankName[i % 13] + suitName[int(i / 13)])
...
>>> showHand(PLAYER)
Threehearts
Ninehearts
Sixdiamonds
Ninediamonds
Twoclubs
>>> showHand(COMP)
Sevenhearts
Sevendiamonds
Sixspades
Queenspades
Kingclubs
```

Comment: Hello thank you for helping me. After implementing your solution to my program it still sometimes outputs 5 cards in player hand and 4 in computer hand or vice versa. Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: @Matteo I'm not sure how that's related to your question. But if you are are just trying to randomly assign cards to two players, `random.shuffle` your deck, then give every-other card, just like you might in real life.

Comment: I am almost done with my program I just need this one error to be fixed which is why I would like to keep my program relatively the same without adding random.shuffle

Comment: perhaps the problem lies in the repeating of the function assignCard() which could cause a number from the list random.sample to equal a number from the same list assigned to either player or computer.

Comment: @Matteo yes, obviously. Which is why you should just shuffle-and-deal...

Comment: if that is the case is there a way to prevent either player's or computer's hand from equalling each other? (without straying from how I coded it)

Comment: My professor doesn't want us to change the algorithm he taught us

Comment: What algorithm is that? What does "straying" mean, exactly? You have to change *something* obviously, because your code is incorrect.

Comment: but he didn't provide us with the commands necessary to accomplish how he wants us to program it.

Comment: @Matteo you seem to want to change your program without changing it. I can't help you accomplish the logically impossible.

Comment: Matteo: If you deal the cards from the same shuffled "deck" for all players, then the cards players get shouldn't repeat (unless there are duplicate cards in the deck)—just like in real life.

Comment: the algorithm of assigning 10 random positions(5 for player and 5 for computer) in the list of 52 cards with a value of either a 1 or a 2 which corresponds to either player(1) or computer(2) and then printing out which hand is which.

Comment: I guess you could sample 10 cards like I said above, then simply assign half to the player and half to the dealer.

Comment: @Matteo there, I added an example of what I meant.

Comment: So I finally figured it out, it was so simple that I feel dumb that I didn't think of it in the first place. I just added an if statement under assignCard(person) to check if the list cardLoc[x] was equal to zero and if it was, to assign it person and if it was not, to run assignCard(person) again. This is what I meant by not changing the algorithm. In your solution it would require me to remove the for loop in main(). Nevertheless I appreciate your help and your intentions.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga what was that you said about changing my program without changing it being logically impossible? Obviously adding a simple if statement resolved the issue, I didn't have to change my code like your solution implies. Perhaps you could learn a thing or two about the basics of programming.